# Is there a way to post something for discussion, rather than ask a question?

Tags: discussion

I like the question / answer format, but I would also find it useful to post a piece that I have written (current subjects include cosmology and thermodynamics) to generate discussion, feedback. Warning: I am not theoretical physicist, so some / all may be fantasy, but still may provoke ideas.

Answer (score 17):

A better site for open discussion is [physicsforums](https://www.physicsforums.com/). This is not what SE does. Vixra is populated with kooks.

Comment: "We wish to discuss mainstream science. That means only topics that can be found in textbooks or that have been published in reputable journals." [Physics Forums Global Guidelines](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/physics-forums-global-guidelines.414380/)

Comment: It’s pretty much guaranteed that any site where anyone can publish their ideas gets populated with a high percentage of kooks.

Answer (score 14):

Ask in [the Physics chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). This is exactly what the chat room is intended for.

What response you get depends on who is in the chat room and how much free time they have, but it costs nothing to ask and the worst that can happen is that no-one answers.